# O que é um peso em uma rede neural?

Tags: redes-neurais

Uma rede neural é composta de vários elementos, como os valores de entradas (x1, x2, x3...) a saída que passa por uma função de ativação, com um bias (viés) que controla o eixo x e mostra onde corta no eixo y, mas o que seria o peso (w)?

Answer (score -2):

Para um neurônio típico, se as entradas forem x1, x2 e x3, os pesos sinápticos a serem aplicados a eles serão denotados como w1, w2 e w3. O peso mostra a eficácia de uma entrada específica. Quanto maior o peso de entrada, mais ela influenciará na rede neural